# Is there syntax highlighting for psql?

Tags: postgresql, syntax-highlighting

Is there some setting or package that I could use to give syntax highlighting to `psql` (the PostgreSQL shell)?

Comment: Shouldn't this be a stackoverflow question? In any case I'm also looking for coloured display of `psql` results or help files, e.g. for `\h select`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just found **pgcli** (https://github.com/dbcli/pgcli) — a postgres client that does auto-completion and syntax highlighting. It looks awesome!

[image: pgcli in action]

### Quick Start

If you already know how to install python packages, then you can simply do:

```
$ pip install pgcli

or

$ brew install pgcli  # Only on OS X
```

If you don't know how to install python packages, please check the 
[detailed instructions](https://github.com/dbcli/pgcli#detailed-installation-instructions).

### Usage

```
$ pgcli [database_name]

or

$ pgcli postgresql://[user[:password]@][netloc][:port][/dbname]
```

### Examples:

```
$ pgcli local_database

$ pgcli postgres://amjith:pa$$w0rd@example.com:5432/app_db
```

Source: https://github.com/dbcli/pgcli

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for pointing it out, added image and more specific info.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question and @honza-kasik 's a great reply. However, to further add to it, it should be pointed out that Debian-based Linux users should install via APT:

```bsh
sudo apt install pgcli
```

Doing this saves a lot of headaches you'd have installing via `pip`